# Lost data while converting image png to base64 string

Tags: php, image, png

I have an image.png which is generated dynamically (barcode) and which is returned to html as

> `<img src="data:image/png;base64,B64STR" />`

but it sometimes get defects (white dots).

To convert image to base64 string I use this code:

```
    ob_start();
    imagepng($img);
    $contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return base64_encode($contents);
```

Can be the output buffer be the cause of lost data? Can I convert the image to base64 some other way?

Answer (score 0):

imagepng return a bool. Use file_get_contents without ob :

```
return base64_encode(file_get_contents($img));
```

Comment: file_get_contents accepts first argument as a filename (path to the file. How can it be type of resource as I asked in my question?

Comment: I don't know, because finally I think your code is right. What return your code ? How is created $img ?